# java class path issue

Tags: java, linux, classpath

Below is my Java code and and which trying to compile one file. I have two linux setups.

The program is not able to set the class path if I use line 1 and comment line 2. The only difference is quotes.

I have observed that this is machine specific. On some machines this classpath with quotes works fine.

I am using Java 1.6 update 24. Any pointers?

I think quotes is for spaces and code should work with quotes.

```
    //String clspath = '"' + this.getClassPath() + '"';  // 1 line
    //String clspath = this.getClassPath();   // 2 line

    String[] compArgs = new String[] {
                    "-classpath", clspath,
                    "-g",
                    "-d", ruleCompDirName,
                    realclassNameFull};
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(out, true);
    int compileStatus = com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(compArgs, pw);

    // Print compiler output
    if (_logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        String compOutput = new String(out.toByteArray());
        _logger.debug(compOutput);
    }
```

Comment: I think you don't need single quotes at all. Why do you need single quote ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess `com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile` ends up by calling an external [`Process`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html).

When using a command-line argument from shell, you need to specify where it starts and where it ends. It is done with whitespaces. It is why you need to quote all arguments that contain spaces. But when starting a process from Java, every argument has it's own position in the corresponding array, so quotes are not needed.

In most cases, if you quote an argument, quotes will be considered PART of the argument, and not the enclosing characters, so, in your case, the compiler will search for a file starting by `"`, which is incorrect.

I'm not sure why in some systems it is accepting the quotes, as it should allways fail...

Comment: I think "modern" Windows interprets/ignores double quotes in paths. This way you do not need to take much care about quoting in CMD.ExE scripts and configuration files (i.e. you can do things like `echo hi > """"C:\"Temp"/hi".txt"""`). On the downside you can not have file names with double quotes (or rather cannot properly handle them via Explorer or CMD.EXE) which is no problem on operating systems with a clean path handling (i.e. `echo hi > "\""` on Linux).